# Better strategy: Use JS SetTimeout to check session on interval, or check session on ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

If a user's session is expired and then they come back and click a button that causes an ajax request to be made, my current method of redirecting to login wasn't working. To resolve this, I implemented the ability to check the session when a request is made which returns a 401 status header if the session is expired. Then in my javascript I redirect to the login page. The downside of this method is that I have to go back and re-implement this across the entire application.

I've read in other places where people have recommended using a timer to check the session periodically in javascript. I like the idea of it automatically checking and redirecting back to the login without user interaction, but I'm wondering if it's just creating a lot of requests to the server where the first method would only make a request when required.

I could also imagine a scenario where you implement both. The timeout is a little longer so if the user catches it before the timer does, the 401 status header would be returned.

I'd be interested to hear how others have implemented this functionality, and what the best strategy really is?  Am I putting too much emphasis on additional calls to the server?

This is my current implementation:

In my base controller:

```
public function is_session_valid()
    {
        $userData = $this->session->userdata('user_data');

        if(!empty($userData)) //session still in place, return true
        {
            return true;
        }
        else  //session has expired.
        {
            $rememberMe = $this->input->cookie('remember_me');

            if(!empty($rememberMe) && $this->Auth_model->verify_auth_token($this->input->cookie('remember_me')))
            {
                //use the cookie to verify the user and log them in.
                $selector = explode(':', $this->input->cookie('remember_me'))[0];
                $this->Auth_model->login_with_cookie($selector);
                $this->session->set_userdata('user_data', $this->Auth_model->get());
                $this->regenerate_session();

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

and then each controller method calls this function like so:

```
if($this->input->is_ajax_request() && !$this->is_session_valid())
{
    $this->output->set_status_header(401);
    exit;
}
```

Right now I'm handling regular page requests and ajax requests differently because I had first implemented the page requests and then discovered when the session times out if the user clicks a button that causes an ajax request, it wasn't getting handled correctly. I think I could probably combine functionality and have it all done in one check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually i'm using a heart-beat myself to check for session expiry but i find your approach is't that bad to check for expiration on every single action (to save user's bandwidth). and i have a better idea for implementing your approach cause of course you can't go though every single method in your entire app to add a check; but if your controllers extends a `MY_Controller` or even better an `Admin_controller`, `Public_Controller` that extends `MY_Controller` then in that controller you can bind the check to that controller's constructor or render method and solve the problem.

Comment: that's actually how i have it implemented at the moment. I have an is_session_valid() method in my base controller that every method calls and then if it returns false I set the http response header to 401. This does simplify the implementation, but I still have to go through every function and add the check. Not that big of a deal, but still..

Comment: But you don't have to go through every single function, just add it to the base controller's constructor as the is_logged_in() is added just there!

Comment: ooohhhh....that's a good call. I don't know why I didn't think of that, because I'm doing the same check for non-ajax calls in the constructor....man, i can't believe i missed that!